# Boost serialization text_iarchive process died

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, ros

I'm using boost::archive for the serialization of my objects. I have my code here:

```
void Tracking::SaveMap() {
    ofstream ofs("/home/yisha/Workspace/Map/map.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << *mpMap;
}

bool Tracking::LoadMap() {
    cout << "\nLoading map..." << endl;

    Map* tmpMap; 
    ifstream ifs("/home/yisha/Workspace/Map/map.txt");
    if(!ifs.good()) {
        printf("ifs not good\n");
        return false;
    }

    printf("after ifstream\n");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    printf("after archive\n");
    ia >> *tmpMap;
    printf("after ia\n");

    mpMap = tmpMap;

    cout << "Loading map finished!" << endl;

    return true;
}
```

The `mpMap` is an object with serialize function implemented.
The map is saved successfully but I cannot verify whether the `map.txt` is correct since I cannot load the map back.
I'm running inside ros and the runtime error is just process died. I've got the output here:

> Loading map...
>   after ifstream
>   after archive
>   [mono-1] process has died [pid 19721, exit code -11, cmd /home/yisha/Workspace/VO/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/Mono __name:=mono __log:=/home/yisha/.ros/log/811c9cf6-68a6-11e6-9123-408d5cb4a2ef/mono-1.log].
>   log file: /home/yisha/.ros/log/811c9cf6-68a6-11e6-9123-408d5cb4a2ef/mono-1*.log
>   all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit

There's no log file in the directory it says.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `tmpMap` is an uninitialised pointer as you never set it to anything.

```
Map* tmpMap;
...
ia >> *tmpMap;
...
mpMap = tmpMap;
```

When pointers are created they don't point to a valid address. This means that when you try to deserialize the archive with `ia >> *tmpMap;` you are putting the data into a dud memory location. This is likely to throw a segmentation fault resulting in the crash.

To fix this you can remove the use of a pointer in this situation so can just change it to:

```
Map tmpMap;
...
ia >> tmpMap;
...
*mpMap = tmpMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're create `mpMap`, but it looks like it's on the heap. In this case, you have two choices. You can serialize the object itself by dereferencing the pointer, like you're doing. The thing is, you'll need an object to *read into* when you load the data back.

```
Map* tmpMap = new Map;
ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(*tmpMap);
```

Make sure you delete `tmpMap` properly.

You can also serialize the pointer itself and boost will take care of memory management:

```
// saving, note that there's no dereferencing
oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(mpMap);

// loading, still no dereferencing
Map* tmpMap; 
ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(tmpMap);
```

What you cannot do is save an object (`*mpMap`) and hope to read it into a pointer that doesn't point to anything (`tmpMap`).

Comment: Hi @isanae I've changed the output to `oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(*mpMap);` and input as `Map* tmpMap = new Map(); ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(*tmpMap);` but I still get the input stream error. Do you have any idea of why it happens?